# PEAR_Exception: DB Error: no such field, while upgrading CiviCRM in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, upgrade

I just tried to update a CiviCRM 5.47.4 installation to the latest 5.51.0 and I am getting this error during the database upgrade process.

Once the upgrade failed I reset both the filesystem and database back to where it was before I had started. So I'm back in 5.47.4. But I don't have a way to go back any farther than that. It was the first time I attempted this upgrade and I'm hoping someone can help me with what I need to do so the upgrade will be able to succeed when I try it again.

I do not see an is_autorun field in my civicrm_queue table so if that was supposed to be created I suppose something failed along the way that I was unaware of.

Error Field Error Value
Type    DB_Error
Code    -19
Message DB Error: no such field
Mode    16
UserInfo    UPDATE civicrm_queue SET runner = "task" WHERE is_autorun = 1 [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'is_autorun' in 'where clause']
DebugInfo   UPDATE civicrm_queue SET runner = "task" WHERE is_autorun = 1 [nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'is_autorun' in 'where clause']

PEAR_Exception: DB Error: no such field in /home/kepw/www/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php on line 922

- DB_Error: DB Error: no such field in unknown on line unknown

Comment: Is this a site where you tried the upgrade more than once? You can get that error if running thru the 5.48 steps again without doing a complete drop and restore from backup before rerunning.

Comment: If not, are you able to see from a backup what your civicrm_queue table looked like in 5.47? There should be a line in the backup file starting with CREATE TABLE civicrm_queue

Comment: Once the upgrade failed I reset both the filesystem and database back to where it was before I had started. So I'm back in 5.47.4. But I don't have a way to go back any farther than that. I see the civicrm_queue table. It was the first time I attempted this upgrade.

Comment: @Demerit I've updated this question and am hoping you'll have more input for me. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how it would be possible to have a 5.47 backup that had never gone past 5.48 that has a civicrm_queue table but doesn't have is_autorun. The only thing I can think is a sequence of failed upgrades that included some 5.48. Since you probably don't have anything in civicrm_queue, try `drop table civicrm_queue`, then create it using https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/4cbeb3a31baea58d44813905e3b131b4ae26bfea/CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/sql/5.47.alpha1.mysql.tpl#L3-L11 (leave out the utf8mb4 if your database is only utf8), then run the upgrade.

Comment: Thank you @Demerit that fixed the issue. Perhaps the restore function I used when the upgrade failed was not restoring things as completely as I assumed. I was successfully able to run the entire upgrade process after dropping and re-creating the civicrm_queue table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments, possibly there was a sequence of failed upgrades and restore where the restore to 5.47 ended up with some changes from 5.48. Fixed in this case by `drop table civicrm_queue`, recreating with https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/4cbeb3a31baea58d44813905e3b131b4ae26bfea/CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/sql/5.47.alpha1.mysql.tpl#L3-L11, and then running the upgrade.